# Tensorflow compatible version for gfile

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Python code which uses Tensorflow module as

```
from tensorflow import gfile
```

However, with the following tf module versions

```
tb-nightly                     2.9.0a20220218
tensorboard-data-server        0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit         1.8.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem   0.24.0
termcolor                      1.1.0
tf-estimator-nightly           2.9.0.dev2022021709
tf-nightly-gpu                 2.9.0.dev20220218
```

I get this error

```
  File "loop_init.py", line 21, in <module>
    import main
  File "/research/reinforcement/minigo/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow import gfile
ImportError: cannot import name 'gfile' from 'tensorflow' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py)
```

Seems like a version mismatch. So, I wonder which Tensorflow version works with gfile. Any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

[gfile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io) api is available inside `tensorFlow.io` module. So you need to use below namespace to import this api:

```
from tensorflow.io import gfile
```